# How to use the Sharepoint Spell Checker in 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-services, spellchecker

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms516167.aspx

Hi,

I have gone through the above link and found that the sharepoint spelllchecker is available and can be used. Can someone give me a sample code on how to implement this on a textbox, as in to check the contents of a textbox and check the spellings.

from what ive read i have been grasp that this will only work for the whole page and not only on a single control.

I need it to only spell check a textbox. Can someone please help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but people may still be looking for this. I'd like to present you with the solution for the edit properties of a library.

If you are in the edit properties of a library, you can add a button to the form and it will automatically check the spelling of the fields on that page. To do this:

1. Find the library in Site Contents.
2. Open the library
3. On the toolbar, click Library/Form Web Parts then Default Edit Form
4. Add a content editor web part and in the source add:

`<button onclick="Spellcheck(); return false;">Check Spelling</button>`

You can also get fancy and add the SharePoint spellcheck image using:
`<img src="/_layouts/15/1033/images/spellingHH.png">`

> This solution will get you spell checking of multiple text boxes, on screen verification, and a popup dialog for suggested spelling, replace, or ignoring words.